# Why would you migrate a Meta Question?

Tags: discussion

Why would you migrate a Meta Question?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question applies to the network as a whole it's sometimes better to migrate it to Meta Stack Overflow.

In this case, though, it looks like the poster was asking about reputation display for his Stack Overflow account, so the question was moved to the appropriate meta.

Comment: It should go to Meta Stack exchange... Not SO. But i guess since there is no Meta Stack exchange, SO gets it. Seems wrong.

Comment: @Morons Meta SO *is* the meta for Stack Exchange. The naming can be confusing, I agree, but MSO not just a per-site meta for Stack Overflow. So the question is in the right place in that sense. (Incidentally, http://meta.stackexchange.com redirects to MSO as well.)

Comment: @Morons I updated my answer -- the question's OP was asking about his SO account, so the question definitely belonged on MSO rather than here.